# Почему для списков del a[i] работает быстрее чем a.pop(i)?

Tags: python

Оказывается!

```
%timeit exp.pop(100000)
43.2 µs ± 16.3 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)

%timeit del exp[100000]
36.2 µs ± 13.7 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

то есть del a[i] работает быстрее чем a.pop(i).  Неужели это из-за того, что a.pop(i) еще возвращает значение? но ведь a.pop(i) - это сишная функция, а del a[i] работает как (внешний) оператор. Кто объяснит?

Между операциями я восстановил исходный список так что дело не в изменении длины.

Comment: Предположу. a.pop это метод объекта, и что там происходит до момента обращения к сишной функции...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Подозреваю, что это накладные расходы на вызов функции:

```
In [32]: import dis

In [33]: dis.dis("lst.pop(0)")
  1           0 LOAD_NAME                0 (l)
              2 LOAD_ATTR                1 (pop)   # Replaces TOS with getattr(TOS, co_names[namei])
              4 LOAD_CONST               0 (0)
              6 CALL_FUNCTION            1         # Calls a callable object with positional arguments. argc indicates the number of positional arguments...
              8 RETURN_VALUE

In [34]: dis.dis("del lst[0]")
  1           0 LOAD_NAME                0 (l)
              2 LOAD_CONST               0 (0)
              4 DELETE_SUBSCR                      # Implements del TOS1[TOS]
              6 LOAD_CONST               1 (None)
              8 RETURN_VALUE
```